# Changing the output of XML feed to something else

Tags: xml, xslt

What i need to do perform here is either parse, decode, encode, reverse, escape or transform this string.

**The source XML/ASHX looks like:**

```
 ...Tournament Description="$333 Gtee R&amp;A" ...
```

**The result needs to look like this:**

```
"$333 Gtee R&A"
```

**My current XSLT looks like:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version = '1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="Tournaments"> 

<table width="850" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="zebra">
  <tr class="zebra">
    <td><xsl:text>Description: </xsl:text></td>
    <td><xsl:text>Starting: </xsl:text></td>
    <td><xsl:text>GameType: </xsl:text></td>
  </tr>
 <xsl:for-each select="Tournament">
  <tr class="zebra">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@Description"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@StartDate"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@GameType"/></td>
  </tr>
   </xsl:for-each>
</table>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can i insert somewhere a magic bullet that will fix the code?

thank you!

yours truly

Horace

Comment: You do understand that your browser will correctly decode the **&amp;** into a single **&**, right? If not, you just need to view it in a browser to see there is no problem. So there actually isn't an issue with that unless you can update your question with additional information that we may be missing.

Comment: thanks Matthew for your reply.

what kind of additional information can i give?

what i mean is this:

my .ashx feed currently look like this:

    Turbo up Fixed Limit Hold&#39;em
    $333 Gtee R&amp;A

The output in my browser looks just like above. The special characters are replaced with &symbols
But output should look like this. 
    Turbo up Fixed Limit Hold'em
    Gtee R+A

Comment: I'm not familiar with an .ashx file but that might be good to update the question with that information. Maybe see if there is a related tag you can add to your question to get people more familiar with that looking at this. Outside of that though, I can't see a reason why your browser wouldn't properly decode those entities unless that has something to do with how you are displaying the information from the .ashx file. Otherwise, when viewing your HTML created by your XSL above in a browser I show it displays correctly.